# I could not install masonry-rails gem in my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, masonry, bundle-install

when I add masonry-rails gem in my gemfile and try bundle install I get this:

```
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
Retrying fetcher due to error (2/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs  from https://rubygems.org/
Retrying fetcher due to error (3/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch  specs from https://rubygems.org/
Retrying fetcher due to error (4/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/
Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/
```

I check the last version for masonry in rubygem and the last one was in 2014...
is masonry still working ? It seems that the problem is from the masonry gem...I try bundle install after I delete it from gem file and it work...
Any one can help with that?

Comment: Let's verify your Gemfile, first line should be `source 'https://rubygems.org'` and there is no space before ?

Comment: @孙悟空 right there is no space before... also If i delete the masonry-rails gem from gemfile and try bundle install it working fine...

Comment: Try run direct `gem install masonry-rails` ?

Comment: @孙悟空 get this error: ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'masonry-rails' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - no such name (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

Comment: Hi it is working now.... I dont know what was the problem but after waiting 30 min it working...thank you anyway for trying to help

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem.
because i was using a virtualbox, and i changed the network config (from NAT to private network) in order to access the rails web server.

So, first, try 
ping rubygems.org

Answer (score 0):

I install masonry-rails gem in rails 5 app and it installed very well.

You can try to install masonry js from below link:

http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the https version of rubygems to http in your Gemfile.